# Strip spaces when saving a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(Django) Trim whitespaces from charField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043012/django-trim-whitespaces-from-charfield)

In ruby on rails is really easy to strip spaces when saving a model. In django what's the best practice?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, also here in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043012/django-trim-whitespaces-from-charfield

Comment: I already saw that, I was hoping there is a  more elegant way....

Comment: Or you could implement a new type of field to do it automatically

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass  For creating your own field like okm suggested

Comment: There's no built in way to do this so you can do it the 'inelegant' way, or either write a custom ModelField or FormField depending on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very easy to override `models.Model` `save` method, to perform any pre svae actions.  The link that `stummjr` also provides an example.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    # some fields here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # strip spaces here
       super(MyClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       # make sure to call parent save method ^
```