# Turn off trimming of whitespace in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a charfield in a django model:

```
sheet = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

I am using the default sqlite database.

When I add a new object that has trailing whitespace at the end of this field, Django automatically trims the string. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: The `model.CharField` doesn't remove whitespace. However, `form.CharField` does that by default which can be turned off by passing [`strip=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip) argument. But it only works with `forms.CharField`. If you're adding the objects via admin, then that might be the reason for auto trimming. I think overriding the admin form remains your only option.

Comment: This was it - I was making the changes in the admin interface which I assume also uses the forms.CharField. Went into the shell and updated it like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TextField and CharField is stripping spaces and blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995764/django-textfield-and-charfield-is-stripping-spaces-and-blank-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the model doesn't trim whitespace but the forms.CharField does. This is used in the admin interface, which I was using to try to perform the update.

I went into the shell (python manage.py shell) and updated the object directly, which worked.