# Django/Python string maintain the number of spaces when save in a model

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

In my django app i have models with CharField or Textfield fields; sometime i need to save in this field strings with more than one single space within word, like for example "hello   world" but after save() process in my db i find thad the 3 spaces become 1.

i try:

```
from django.utils import safestring
```

but i don't know how to apply at the whole models fields

How can i maintain the exact string i write in my textbox with the exact number of spaces i need?

So many thanks in avance

Answer (score 0):

Set strip to false in the init of your ModelForm:

```
  self.fields['myfield'].strip = False
```

If you aren't using a ModelForm you can create a custom Text Field, like said here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709539/5434276