# Disable strip white space from models.CharField

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I have a django application using models.CharField. The issue is trailing whitespace is removed, which weirdly enough, I DO NOT WANT TO HAPPEN.

I am only accessing the field through the Admin, not a form. I understand through other posts that forms have an strip = False option, but models do not.

Is there an easy way I can achieve this?

Comment: A `ModelAdmin` *has* a form. You can override that form, and thus specify how to handle certain fields.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Willem, but I wasn't exactly sure how to do that.

That said, I've worked it out myself, with a little help from
[Django TextField/CharField is stripping spaces/blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995764/django-textfield-charfield-is-stripping-spaces-blank-lines).

Step by step for those still learning, like me:

1. Define a custom form, overriding the **init** method (forms.py)

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].strip = False

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

2. Reference the custom form when defining the model admin (admin.py)

```
from .forms import YourForm

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_display, ordering etc.

    form = YourForm
```