# Django - enforce stripping whitespaces in CharField from the model

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to populate data into the following model from a csv and using update_or_create() in a loop to do that.

```
class TargetPlace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The csv may have some entries which have leading or trailing white spaces and I want to get rid of those.

I saw that CharField's in Django >=1.9 have a [strip](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip) argument that takes care of this by default (since its True by default). I am using Django 1.10 but still seeing duplicate entries in the model (those with and without leading white spaces).

Does the strip argument not work that way?

Comment: Yes, it does work that way.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Andrey. I got confused with the CharField in a Form (vs Model). See my answer below (and please let me know if you agree)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Django) Trim whitespaces from charField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043012/django-trim-whitespaces-from-charfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I got confused with the CharField in a Form vs CharField in a Model. [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) in a Model does not seem to have any such argument

Comment: I was just looking at the source code and you are right, it doesn't have any such argument.

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38320995/15267030) answer throws some more light